# Recover image from its X and Y gradients

Tags: image-processing, integration, gradient

I have a single channel image from which I can compute its vertical and horizontal gradients. I would like to make some operations in the gradient domain and subsequently recover back the scalar field (image) which results after the gradient modification. Any idea how to do this? I know if I integrate the modified gradient I can get back the function up to a constant but I would have two different constants C_x and C_y from the partial X and Y derivatives. Also, I don't have an intuition of how to "integrate" a vector field as the gradient.

Thanks!

Comment: What method are you using to calculate the gradients? Convolution? E.g. a sobel operator?

Comment: I don't have restrictions on that. Could be any. Are there any methods which are easier to integrate to get the scalar field back?